# Proof whether or not 1/k by 1/(k+1) rectangles fit inside a unit square

Tags: geometry, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, infinity

I am reading Concrete Mathematics and came across an interesting problem, number 37 of chapter 2. The answers to exercises lists no known answer to this problem:

- **Will all the 1/k by 1/(k+1) rectangles, for k $\ge$ 1, fit together inside a 1 by 1 square? (Recall that their areas sum to 1)**

My question is: Has a solution been found in the years after the book's publishing? Mathematics is a very large field, and much of the terminology that might aid in googling I am not yet aware of.

Comment: This is one of my favorite problems.

Comment: If you find a solution, please let me know :-)

Answer (score 4):

See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34145/can-we-cover-the-unit-square-by-these-rectangles).

Comment: The D.Jennings mentioned there is our very own [Derek Jennings](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/1301/derek-jennings)!

Comment: @Moron: Yes it is! I said that in my answer but edited it.